# How do I nurture my pets?

Tags: fluff-friends-rescue

In Fluff Friends Rescue, sometimes a message pops up above a pet that is either in a Vet Station, Food Station, Fun Station or Grooming Station that says "Tap to Nurture". This is different than the usual "Tap to Manage" message that lets you know how long it will be before you can place a pet up for adoption - there is no time countdown with this message. When I tap on it, my choices are to Fast Heal my pet (which costs premium currency that you either get for levelling or by paying real-world money) or to release the pet from care.

I don't understand why I am getting this message, and I also wonder if I have to spend premium currency to fix it, or if there is something else I can do (like just waiting things out?)

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You spend coins, release the pets, and/or contact the developers if it's a defect.** "The nurture function of the game is a second chance to save your pets that may have sat un-loved for too long." If you didn't leave your pets un-loved for too long, then it is a defect in the vein of [this one](https://getsatisfaction.com/fluff_friends_rescue/topics/update_as_of_january_30_2012) and contacting the developers may be your only hope at a resolution. If you did leave them un-loved, then you should probably do as the prompt suggests (fast heal or release). Waiting likely won't fix this in the short term and in the long term if it is a defect, waiting is your only option.